# Flexibility of template alias in C++0x

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typename

As I understand, template aliases in C++0x will allow us to do the following:

```
template <typename T>
using Dictionary = std::map< std::string, T >;

Dictionary<int> ints;
ints[ "one" ] = 1;
ints[ "two" ] = 2;
```

I have two questions:

First, will we be able to do this (bind to any type, or just templates):

```
template <typename Iter>
using ValueType = std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
```

Second, will using the aliases require usage of the `typename` keyword in templates, e.g.:

```
template <typename Iter>
typename ValueType<Iter> sum(Iter first, Iter last) { ... }
// ^ required?
```

Or is it required in the alias declaration?

```
using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
//                   ^ required?
```

Or neither?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
template <typename Iter>
using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
```

as with your second one.

Source:
http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#template-alias

Their example is:

```
template<int N>
    using int_exact = typename int_exact_traits<N>::type;  // define alias for convenient notation
```

Answer (score 3):

`typename` is required when a member type follows the `::` operator and a template-id precedes it.

The usage of `typename` you mention isn't specific to template aliases nor is it required unless you're aliasing to a member such as `::type`, but that is a common use case.

For example, there's no `typename` when introducing a simple alias name to an existing template.

```
template< typename x >
class bar;

template< typename x >
using foo = bar< x >; // no typename needed
```